# how to check the errors that generated in the android emulator for ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-emulator, ionic3

In my ionic project, I have not found any errors( i got to know when I ran the command `ionic serve`). I think I getting some errors while performing some operation. I'm running it in the emulator. How can I check the errors that occur while running the app in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic serve runs the app in the browser, meaning that any errors can be observed as on a normal webpage. 
The best way to do that is to use browser builtin developer tools. Most browsers (Chrome, Mozilla, ...) use a F12 shortcut to open it. In Safari you have to enable Development tab in the menu bar ([Instructions](https://support.apple.com/sl-si/guide/safari/use-the-safari-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac)) and then open it there.

In Developer Tools there is a "console" tab where all outputs are presented. Red color indicates an error.

Comment: yeah i know it I'm asking is there any way to see the errors when we deploy the app in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug you app using google chrome. Go to `chrome://inspect/` from your chrome browser. Then you can see apps running your emulator. click on your app and go to console. using console you can find errors.

Comment: yeah i know it I'm asking is there any way to see the errors when we deploy the app in the emulator?

Comment: no, actually I want to test it for Cordova plugin. so I can't run it in the browser.

Comment: No problem. if there is any error with plugin and running it with a real device or emulator further you can see errors using above mentioned way. I can give an answer if you update your question with your code implementation of used cordova plugin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847810/linkedin-oauth-2-0-in-ionic-3 if you can help me in this please post your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for cordova plugins - some of them will work only on real device (for example camera). But you might want to try `Toast` for checking for errors. Just replace `console.log()` with
`this.toast.show('message', 'duration', 'position').subscribe();`

Check [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/toast/) for instruction how to implement toast.

Hope this helps!